# FindFormula and Piecewise

Tags: interpolation

The command FindFormula does not give me a right formula for simple data like this:

```
rtable={{0,28.52},{1/4,29.1},{1/2,28.48},{3/4,28.808},{1,28.845},{5/4,28.845},{3/2,28.01},{7/4,28.375},{2,28.04},{9/4,28.04},{5/2,26.97},{11/4,27.44},{3,27.8},{13/4,28.35},{7/2,27.7},{15/4,28.186},{4,28.525},{17/4,28.945},{9/2,28.51},{19/4,28.766},{5,28.79},{21/4,29.295},{11/2,28.66},{23/4,28.97},{6,29.3},{25/4,29.825},{13/2,29.17},{27/4,29.427},{7,29.26},{29/4,29.33},{15/2,28.66},{31/4,29.143},{8,28.89},{33/4,28.895},{17/2,28.38},{35/4,28.531},{9,28.715},{37/4,28.89},{19/2,28.57},{39/4,28.653},{10,28.54},{41/4,28.69},{21/2,28.15},{43/4,28.296},{11,28.155},{45/4,28.23},{23/2,27.61},{47/4,27.873},{12,27.75},{49/4,27.849},{25/2,27.035},{51/4,27.56},{13,27.01},{53/4,27.23},{27/2,26.84},{55/4,27.04},{14,27.025},{57/4,27.049},{29/2,26.68},{59/4,26.873},{15,27.02},{61/4,27.6},{31/2,26.967},{63/4,27.144},{16,27.27},{65/4,27.38},{33/2,27.13},{67/4,27.266},{17,27.5},{69/4,27.69},{35/2,27.35},{71/4,27.454},{18,27.77},{73/4,27.9},{37/2,27.58},{75/4,27.738},{19,27.93},{77/4,28.08},{39/2,27.67},{79/4,27.8},{20,28.335},{81/4,28.63},{41/2,28.27},{83/4,28.463},{21,28.43},{85/4,28.74},{43/2,28.2},{87/4,28.27},{22,28.76},{89/4,28.905},{45/2,28.46},{91/4,28.655}}
```

[image: data in blue findformula result in green]

Mathematica only returns a constant when the data ask for a piecewise interpolation of fisrt order polinomial.

Any sugestion?  I have use several versions of

```
 FindFormula[rtable, x, 4,  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality" , TargetFunctions->{Times, Plus}]
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why, but scaling so to make all x values integers gives better results.

```
formula = FindFormula[{4 #1, #2} & @@@ rtable, x, SpecificityGoal -> ∞, 
  TargetFunctions -> {Times, Plus}, RandomSeeding -> 100] /. x -> 4 x
```

[image]

```
Plot[formula, {x, 0, 22.75}, Epilog -> {Red, Point[rtable]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it is solved!!No idea why it is important for FindFormula the x coordinate

Comment: Is there any way to avoid the discontinuities when using this approach?  I love how it comes up with the solution but have a formula for which I'd prefer to avoid the discontinuities that arise similar to what is shown above.